# How to inject a particular implementation in an abstract class (both present inside a library) in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I've created a plain Java - Maven library which has one abstract class A and its two implementation A1 and A2. Other projects will use this library.
I want to know the various ways in which the other project can specify that which implementation should be used for the abstract class with minimal code.

For now, I'm testing the library in other project by:

```
    A a = new A1();
    a.func();
```

But this is tight coupling and if anyone wants to change the implementation, the class needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way is to do it inside some configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean public void myBean () {
    return new A1(); 
    // return new A2();
  }
}
```

You can do whatever logic you want inside the myBean method (if...else) to determine which one you want to instantiate.

A better way is to use conditionals. Look for example at @ConditionalOnProperty, which decides upon the presence of a given value in application configuration.
More generally, you can look at @Conditional and related annotations. You can check if a given class exists or not in the classpath, whether a given bean is loaded, environment variables, application configuration, combine multiple conditionals, and many more.

Many configuration classes like this with conditionals exist inside Spring itself, so you don't have to configure anything for simple cases.

Comment: But these annotations are Spring specific. What can be done for plain java?

Comment: You have included the tags related to spring, so I logically assumed that you were already using it. For plain Java you have basically three ways to inject a dependency: via constructor, via setter and via field. At some point you will need to make some external configuration and/or some introspection/reflection if you don't want to have an hard-coded logic.